# Force Airflow's backfill command to run sequentially

Tags: python, python-2.7, airflow

Is there any way that I can run backfill sequentially without doing multitasking? E.g., if I run the backfill with several dates such as
airflow backfill [dag] -s "2017-07-01" -e "2017-07-10", is there any way to finish every dag before running to the next day? Right now its finishing all days of each task before going to the next task.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `max_active_runs` parameter of your DAG to 1 which will make sure that only one DAG run for that dag will get scheduled at the same time. https://pythonhosted.org/airflow/code.html?highlight=concurrency#models

If you need your entire dag to be complete before moving forward you can add an `ExternalTaskSensor` to the start of your DAG and a `DummyOperator` collection task at the end. Then set the ExternalTaskSensor to trigger on the DummyOperator at the end of the previous run.

```
dag = DAG(dag_id='dag')

wait_for_previous_operator = ExternalTaskSensor(\
        task_id='wait_for_previous',
        external_dag_id='dag',
        external_task_id='collection',
        execution_delta=schedule_interval,
        dag=dag)

collection_operator = DummyOperator(\
        task_id='collection',
        dag=dag)


wait_for_previous_operator.set_downstream(your_other_tasks_list)
collection_operator.set_upstream(your_other_tasks_list)
```

Comment: Hi. max_active_runs is already set to 1.
In fact, only one dag runs at the time. But it tries to finish all tasks of the same kind (throughout all dates) before proceeding to the next task in the queue.

Comment: Both in the same DAG? Let me try that. I think ExternalTaskSensors are supposed to be used for different dags. Let's see!

Comment: Hi. When you type "your_other_tasks_list", if I have like 5 tasks should I write the last task, which is always the last one to execute, on both set_downstream and set_upstream lines that you wrote? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I cant manage to trigger the "Dummy operator at the end of the previous run". I dont know how to do that. It seems that your code will always wait for the collection operator at the end of the current dag run, which never happens obviously.

Comment: Remember I am talking about backfilling, Dag is the same, only it runs for several days.

Comment: You need to set the execution_delta on the ExternalTaskSensor to be the same as the schedule_interval of your dag. If that is configured properly, the ExternalTaskSensor will wait for the collection task of the dag run which started on current_schedule_date - execution_delta

Comment: Okay, makes sense for the 2nd and nth runs. But what about the first one? How is it going to wait for a task to be finished if its the first run of the backfill and there is no run "behind it"? Sorry maybe I am confused.

Comment: That's a good point. We have a bit of a coldstart problem here. In that case I would first create the dag with only the collection task at the end and not the ExternalTaskSensor at the beginning and backfill only the first run. Then, add the ExternalTaskSensor to the dag and backfill the remaining items.

Comment: @MatthijsBrouns How do I set `execution_delta` if my `schedule_interval` is a cron string (e.g. `"0 6 1 * *"`)?